# Shortest path that can be split into contiguous segments of 5 edges connecting 6 distinct nodes in an unweighted graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, linear-complexity, programming-contest

The following problem (I'm paraphrasing) appeared in the 2019 Balkan Olympiad in Informatics:

> Five friends are on a road trip in a country with $N$ cities and $M$ bidirectional roads joining them. They start in city $1$ and wish to end in city $N$.
>
> All of them love driving, so they move in the following fashion:
>
> - Each day, they start in the city they ended at the previous day (city $1$ on the first day) and follow a path consisting of exactly five roads (i.e. they visit six cities and the first visited city is the last visited city of the previous day).
> - They may visit a city multiple times across multiple days, but they may not visit a city multiple times in the same day.
> - They can't stop in the middle of the path: if they visit city $N$ after using $k < 5$ roads on some day, they can't end their trip.
>
> Find the shortest path needed to complete this road trip, or determine that it isn't possible. In the case that there are multiple shortest paths, find the lexographically smallest one when looking at only the sequence formed by the ($5k+1$)-th cities visited on the path (i.e. city $1$, ..., city $N$)
>
> $N \leq 10^5$ and $M \leq 5 \cdot 10^5$.

The official problem statement can be found [on the contest website](https://boi2019.epy.gr/?p=747) (day 2 problem 2).

I haven't been able to find an efficient solution to this problem (from both asking others and searching online), and nobody solved it in the contest. I currently have no idea how to even approach it.

Is there an efficient algorithm to solve this problem, perhaps even for $k$ friends instead of five friends? Since $N$ and $M$ are so large, the algorithm should be linear or linearithmic (when implemented in C++, the code should run for at most 1s in the worst case).

Comment: My suggestion: Create a new graph in which there is an edge $(u, v)$ exactly when there is a simple path of length 5 between $u$ and $v$ in the original graph, and run BFS on it. The edges leaving each vertex can be found using a BFS limited to depth 5 starting at that vertex. Not sure if this will be fast enough though.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I believe that the resulting graph could potentially have $\mathcal O(N^2)$ edges, so that would be too slow. Also, I believe that finding those edges would take something like $\mathcal O(N^5)$ time in the worst case (something like a neural net with five layers) due to the restriction of each day's path not being allowed to cross itself.

Comment: You can find the distance-5 adjacency graph using matrix multiplication, but the problem is that it allows visiting the same city twice in one day. I'm not sure if there's a way to account for that.

Comment: There might well be too many edges, but in any case this graph is the graph that needs to be searched implicitly (even if you do not explicitly construct the graph) so this may be unavoidable. A limited-depth BFS takes only $O(n)$ time and finds simple paths (shortest paths are always simple), so doing this for each node is at worst $O(n^2)$ time -- a lot, but far short of $O(n^5)$.

Comment: I think it may be related to the property of being planar: when either $K_{33}$ or $K_5$ are induced subgraphs, then the solution should always exist. Otherwise, the graph is planar, and it may be simpler to work with its cycles.

Comment: @Dmitri when the whole graph is $K_5$, the solution doesn't exist though

Comment: @Dmitry A planar graph don't have $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as _minors_, not only induced subgraphs.  It's also not enough to answer yes/no, you should give shortest solution.  Third, there is nothing about the graph being planar in the problem, is there?

Comment: I think the idea of treating "dense parts" (where we can easily sidetrack to increase path length by a small amount) and "sparse parts" with many degree-2 vertices (where we can reduce the graph and/or perform BFS efficiently) separately will help. Note the solution could be arbitrarily worse than the true shortest path (consider a circle of 1003 vertices, with start and finish at distance 3), and even on a tree could require sidetracking arbitrarily far down a branch that is not on the path from start to finish.

Comment: If the shortest path has length a multiple of 5, it's clearly optimal. Otherwise, if the shortest path's length is 4 mod 5, then there is an optimal solution with length 1 greater iff some shortest path includes a triangle edge, which can be checked for in $O(|E|)$ time by performing BFS, then repeatedly removing all non-finish vertices with no neighbour at greater depth, and checking if there are any edges between vertices at the same depth in the graph that remains (this can be done quickly by maintaining counts of same- and different-depth edges).

Comment: @PålGD, `there is nothing about the graph being planar in the problem`: I want to separate two cases: 1) the graph has $K_5$/$K_{33}$, and therefore the solution always exists (with some details which should be easy to handle); 2) the graph is planar, and therefore it may be easier to work with it (since its cycles has a better structure). I agree with your other comments. Moreover, I don't know how to efficiently check if the graph is planar and how exactly use this fact.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, It might be possible to find it using matrix multiplication. If $\equiv$ is an equivalence relation on $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, let $S_\equiv$ denote the set of all paths $v_0 \to v_1 \to v_2 \to v_3 \to v_4 \to v_5$ such that $i \equiv j \implies v_i=v_j$. Maybe we can count $|S_\equiv|$ using matrix multiplication for each $\equiv$? If so using inclusion-exclusion it would be possible to compute the number of simple paths of length 5 from $v_0$ to $v_5$ for each pair $v_0,v_5$ using 203 matrix multiplications, i.e., a constant number of matrix mults.

Comment: @D.W. wouldn't that be at least $\mathcal O(N^3)$ from matrix multiplication though?

Comment: @AndiQu No: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Computational_complexity.

Comment: The adjacency matrix would be both sparse and boolean, so you should be able to do it even faster than usual.

Comment: @Dmitry if you believe the non-planar cases are easy, just glue a $K_5$ on the start vertex, it doesn't change the solution ... (i.e., add a $K_4$ as neighbors to $v_1$).

Comment: @PålGD: Interestingly, gluing a $K_6$ at the start (or end) vertex makes the solution trivial.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I don't see how it makes the solution trivial, but that could very well just be me being dense.

Comment: @PålGD: If the original graph has a shortest path with length a multiple of 5, that is the optimal solution. Otherwise, suppose the shortest path has length $k \mod 5$: Initially take any 5-path into the glued $K_6$, and then (on the second 5-path) "waste" $5-k$ steps within the glued $K_6$ before reemerging at the start vertex and then following the shortest path to the finish, which will now end at the end of a 5-path. This solution contains just 1 more 5-path, so it is optimal.

Comment: @j_random_hacker That would give you *a* shortest path, but not the lexographically smallest one though

Comment: @j_random_hacker Also, I don't see how this makes it _trivial_ to implement?  You are only guaranteeing that it is a yes-instance?

Comment: @AndiQu: True, some other equal-length but lexicographically smaller path already might already exist in the original graph. That case could be avoided by requiring the glued $K_6$ to use vertices numbered lower than all other vertices in the graph (we are talking about making arbitrary changes to the graph anyway).

Comment: @PålGD: Well, the problem is reduced to running a single BFS and taking every 5th vertex -- not sure how much simpler it could get at this point? As Andi points out, the $K_6$ vertices would need to be lower-numbered than any other vertex in the graph to guarantee the lexicographic ordering condition is met.

Comment: Maybe my original comment was not clear -- I'm not proposing a solution technique to the general problem, I'm saying that any problem that already has a particular structure (namely a $K_6$ that includes the start vertex and uses low vertex numbers) has a trivial solution.

Comment: So I've been in contact with one of the competitors who knows the problem author, and apparently: 1) The author actually originally proposed a solution that ran in $\mathcal O(NM)$ time (rip) using "a meet in the middle approach with a lot of casework", and 2) "The optimal solution is probably a BFS with some really clever pruning, with linear complexity". I haven't been able to find the person who proposed the linear solution though :(

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure we are talking about a solvable problem. I've seen problems where test cases were simply too weak and therefore even an obviously infeasible solution went through. I don't intend to offend the authors, but the words "some really clever pruning" make me feel that this is the case here.